# Confused about YOLO Process

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

In order to get a grasp of the concept, I read this article written by [Mauricio Menegaz](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-yolo-f5a74bbc7967) and watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTlwl2bv0Tg) by Deeplearning.ai on YouTube but I got confused at the S x S x (B * 5 +C) part. I know that the S x S stands for the grid size, 5 stands for the components of the bounding box, and C is for the classes. Is B the same as the anchor boxes? If in case I only want to detect one class (e.g. license plate), does that mean there will only be 1 B?

EDIT
Are bounding boxes created on the image prior to it being fed to the neural networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is B the same as the anchor boxes?

Yes, It is. B is number of anchors boxes

> If in case I only want to detect one class (e.g. license plate), does that mean there will only be 1 B?

No, In this case, C = 1. But if you know in advance the width/height ratio of object you need to detect and this ratio does not change much between viewpoint, you may only need anchor box that match this ratio, so in your case of license plate, B can be 1 too

But if you need to detect cars for example, you may need more anchor boxes because width/height ratio of cars vary much between viewpoint

Comment: Thank you for the input! Are the bounding boxes created in the image before the image is sent to the neural network, or is it after it goes through the neural network?

Comment: @Maning Did you mean anchor boxes? We had anchor boxes before sending image through the neural network. You can think anchor boxes (or prior box) is a way to parameterize the output of network. The output of the network then is decoded to produce bounding boxes

Comment: I honestly could not tell them apart, does that mean that the anchor boxes are placed around the detected objects prior to sending the image through the neural network? I'm terribly sorry, I really have plenty of questions about this matter.

Comment: B anchor boxes are placed at each grid cell in image. Bounding boxes are predicted by offset from these anchor boxes. You can find more information here [https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at this implementation:
https://github.com/1991viet/Yolo-pytorch